# Get Integrated Brier Score for each cycle using R library pec

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I want to compare different models for survival analysis. To do so I use the "pec" R package. I use 10-fold cross validation. To compare the different models I run the model for 30 cycles. As result I can get the (i) Integrated Brier Score (IBS) of the average pec curve, (ii) crossvalErr for this pec curve, and (iii) the crossvalErr for each individual cycle. However, I would like to  be able to get the IBS for each cycle, at different times.

```
# create a fit
fit <-Surv(survival,censored)~v1+v2+v3+v4

# models
cph <- selectCox(fit, data=data, rule="aic")
rsf <- rfsrc(fit, data=data, forest=True, ntree=1000)
cforest <- pecCforest(fit, data=data, controls=cforest_classical(ntree=1000))

fitpec <- pec(list("selectcox" = fitcox, "rsf" = fitrsf, "cforest" =  fitcforest), data = dd_Ex, formula = Surv(surv_m,Censored)~1, 
          splitMethod = "cv10", B=20, keep.index=TRUE, keep.matrix=TRUE)
```

To get the IBS I use the code below, but this only gives me the IBS of the average pec:

```
crps(fitpec, times=c(12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 120, 240, 480), what="crossvalErr")

Integrated Brier score (crps):

 IBS[0;time=12) IBS[0;time=24) IBS[0;time=36) IBS[0;time=48) IBS[0;time=60) IBS[0;time=120) IBS[0;time=240)
[1,]          0.015          0.068          0.121          0.153          0.168           0.168           0.133
[2,]          0.014          0.058          0.093          0.110          0.115           0.108           0.081
[3,]          0.013          0.053          0.089          0.107          0.116           0.116           0.091
[4,]          0.012          0.050          0.083          0.099          0.106           0.104           0.078
 IBS[0;time=480)
[1,]           0.095
[2,]           0.059
[3,]           0.070
[4,]           0.051
```

I also tried to use the crossValErrMat, which contains the data for the pec curves of all cycles, but that gives me an error:

```
crps(fitpec30R$CrossValErrMat[[1]]$Reference, times=c(12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 120, 240, 480), what="crossvalErr")

Error: class(object)[1] == "pec" is not TRUE
```

How can I find the IBS for each cycle? Thank you!

Comment: In the end I found the answer. This was not integrated in the pec R package at the time. So I had to rerun the model 10 times and save the IBS for each run.